# Ignore text marked as No Proofing language

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with some text marked as Review/Language/Do not check spelling or grammar. Why is my code not considering "Proofing"?

```
Sub SentenceProofing()
    Dim iWords As Integer
    Dim Text As String
    Dim oRange As range

    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.range

    If Not ActiveDocument.Saved Then
        ActiveDocument.Save
    End If

    'Set number of words
    iWords = 15

    With oRange.Find
         .NoProofing = False
         For Each MySent In oRange.Sentences
            If MySent.Words.Count > iWords Then
               ActiveDocument.Comments.Add _
               range:=MySent, Text:="Sentence longer than 15 words"
            End If
         Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `NoProofing` applies to `With oRange.Find` but has no connection with the following loop, which does not use `Find`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```vb
Sub SentenceProofing()
    
    Const iWords As Long = 15 'use Const for fixed values
    
    Dim mySent

    With ActiveDocument
        
        If Not .Saved Then .Save
    
        For Each mySent In .Range.Sentences
            If Not mySent.NoProofing Then
                If mySent.Words.Count > iWords Then
                   .Comments.Add Range:=mySent, _
                       Text:="Sentence longer than 15 words"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you suggested not only solves the issue but it also simplifies my code. Thank you very much